# Spring Bean naming when using programmatic configuration

Tags: java, spring, configuration

When i define a define a bean using the XML configuration I do not need to enter a name, for example:

```
<beans>
  <bean class="foo.Bar" />
  <bean class="foo.Bar" />
</beans>
```

The names will internal be set to something like `foo.bar$1` (or something like that I don't have the exact schema in mind right now).

However, when I define the beans using the Java configuration the name is implicitely deriven from the name of the annotated method:

```
@Configuration
public class DummyConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Bar bar1() {
    return new Bar();
  }

  @Bean
  public Bar bar2() {
    return new Bar();
  }

}
```

Here the beans are named `bar1` and `bar2`.

Now, when I have a modular application strucure, where multiple configurations contribute to a single application context I don't see a way of creating multiple instances of `Bar` while making sure one doesn't overwrite the other.

For example, one part of my application defines the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationForModuleA {

  @Bean
  public FooManager fooManager() {
    return new FooManagerImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public SomeListener someListener() {
    return new FooSomeListener();
  }

}
```

And another part (which doesn't know about the first one) defines this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationForModuleB {

  @Bean
  public BarManager barManager() {
    return new BarManagerImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public SomeListener someListener() {
    return new BarSomeListener();
  }

}
```

What happens is that only one `SomeListener` implementation will be made available in the context because both listener implementations are defined under the name `someListener` and the last one defined will overwrite the first one.

Is there a way for me to tell Spring not to use the name of the method for the bean? I know that I could also use `@Bean("explicitName")` but that wouldn't solve my problem. I would still have to invent some kind of naming schema and apply that schema to all my bean declarations making sure that the names are unique. When using XML Spring takes care of this, so is there a way that the Java configuration will do this as well?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but... To making sure one bean doesn't overwrite other you can place the different mudules as child contexts, if that fits your case. The idea is that the child context can see the parent's beans, but parent don't know about the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to tell Spring not to use the name of the method for the bean?

Short answer: **no**.

I thought that plugging in a customized [`BeanNameGenerator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanNameGenerator.html) would solve your problem, but apparently no `BeanNameGenerator` is used for generating bean names of beans defined in `@Configuration` classes *(or at least not in spring 3.2.x & spring 4.0.x)*.

When you take a look at [`ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-context/3.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java#184) *(line 184)*, you'll notice that determining the bean name is pretty hard-coded; if available, the first name defined on the `@Bean` annotation is used, otherwise the name of the method is used.